# Get all post_id's from current loop in array

Tags: wordpress

So, I'm trying to get all the post_id's from my current loop and store them in an array. I've been reading forums from an hour and non are doing what I'm trying. I've come a long way. And I think I'm almost there. But I could need soms help with the last step.

What I've got so far:

I start my loop with a new `WP_Query` and add `$post_ids = array();` and after the `while` I add `$post_ids[] = get_the_ID();`

```
    <?php $the_query = new WP_Query($args); if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) { 
                $post_ids = array();
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $post_ids[] = get_the_ID();
    ?>

        // Do stuff

    <?php }} else { ?>
      <h3>Noting found, try again</h3>
    <?php } ?>
```

After the whole loop I do the following:

```
<pre><?php var_dump($post_ids); ?></pre>
```

This gives me the following:

```
array(19) {
  [0]=>
  int(1938)
  [1]=>
  int(1642)
  [2]=>
  int(1217)
  [3]=>
  int(1182)
  [4]=>
  int(1588)
  [5]=>
  int(1180)
  [6]=>
  int(1088)
  [7]=>
  int(1290)
  [8]=>
  int(1938)
  [9]=>
  int(1894)
  [10]=>
  int(1586)
  [11]=>
  int(1176)
  [12]=>
  int(1174)
  [13]=>
  int(1219)
  [14]=>
  int(1756)
  [15]=>
  int(1922)
  [16]=>
  int(1200)
  [17]=>
  int(1803)
  [18]=>
  int(1553)
}
```

These are all the post_id's I need. But I would like them to have them like: 1938,1643, etc.. so I can use them in an WP_Query again. Do's anyone have an idea how to continue?

Comment: you can json_encode them

Comment: https://www.tehplayground.com/sDCuEv8ARaOTzXWE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply sort your array:

```
sort($post_ids);// for example
var_dump($post_ids);
```

Check also this [links](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp) for more sorting options - ASC, DESC etc. etc.

Comment: This still shows the array like `[0]=> int(1088)   [1]=>  int(1174)` using `print_r` look a bit more manageable but still has the `[0] =>` in front of it.

Comment: so you really don't want an array - you want a comma seperated string

Comment: aaaa ok ... that's another thing I didn't understand you correctly ... But why would you want the IDs' as a string ? If you're about to use these IDs' in query again, isn't it more logical to keep the array ?  You can get posts by array of their IDs' ...

Comment: Your sort option did work. Had to look at the link you gave me. I have a list of id's now separated by a comma. And I'm trying to store them in a session. But this isn't working. But this issue is solved.

Comment: I've just started to write another answer since I though you wanted a string of IDs' from this array, butt nice your issue is solved :)

Comment: If you think that would be better? I could still use some help :)

Comment: No, since you're gonna use it for another query it's better to keep the array